# How do I script juju deployment?

Tags: scripts, juju

I have been working on a few juju charms and am ready to start testing a deployment of our services.  Is there a standard method for deploying an environment?  For instance, do I have to manually type, juju deploy charm xxx from the command line?  Can I build a charm that deployes and configures other charms?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use a bash script with the commands,and a config file with options.

Comment: Do you have multiple config files for each charm?  What does your config file contain (host details, ie EC2 or Openstack)?

Comment: You could, but I use just one for all. Host details are placed in the environment file.

Answer (score 5):

You can automate Juju deployments with Juju Deployer:

- https://launchpad.net/juju-deployer

This is still in-progress, but you can find the documentation here:

- http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/